# Do any outdoor sound sensors exist?

Tags: sensors, audio, sound

I recently had an F/A-18 jet fly over my house and was amazed at how loud it was. That set me to wondering how loud it actually was.

Do any outdoor sensors exist that can track decibel level?

Comment: Are you asking about senros with an internet connection?

Comment: Yes, I'd like it connected remotely

Comment: go a step further, noise cancellation!

Answer (score 7):

Try pairing a microphone with your favorite IoT platform. The problem with this approach is that, initially, you would have to find a way to calibrate it.

Another option would be the [Grove (Arduino)](http://wiki.seeed.cc/Grove-Loudness_Sensor/).

As for the "outdoor-ness" of a sensor, just shield it from the weather and other disrupting elements.

Comment: That Grove sensor looks great, but it looks like it caps out at 66 dB :(

Comment: Getting from a microphone to a sound level measurement ins't trivial, even before you worry about calibration.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yeah, I agree that it's not linear, but we all have to start somewhere. I think trial-by-fire is a good start.

Comment: And how do you get a proper calibration in the range of an F/A-18?

Comment: @Helmar That's the secret. You don't. Instead, one may go to a studio which can produce equal, or louder, calibrated sound levels.

Answer (score 6):

There is a product called [IoTSENS Sound and Noise Sensor](http://www.iotsens.com/sensors_en/sound-and-noise-sensor/). As the specification say, it has following features.

- Identify areas of high sound intensity of 30-100 dB
- Low maintenance costs
- Continuous Measurement
- Improved sound environment management
- Indoor and outdoor application
- Direct connection to *SIGFOX* and *LoRa* communications

Another one is [TA120](https://www.cesva.com/en/products/sensors-terminals/TA120/), which is also be used in outdoors, with [**IP65** rating](http://www.dsmt.com/resources/ip-rating-chart/). It can communicate through,

- Ethernet (RJ45)
- loop 4-20 mA
- Wi-Fi
- 3G modem

(Ethernet is the default option, you can select other options too).

Answer (score 4):

They do already exist, though they're not easy to find.  Here's a bluetooth one [on ebay](http://www.ebay.com/p/Sl5868-Digital-Sound-Level-Meter-Bluetooth-30-130-DB-Decibel-Noise-Pressure/1037609391) for instance.  Obviously, however, in order to remotely use that one, you would have to have it constantly paired with a computer that is nearby and connected to the internet.

However, there are also wifi enabled digital sound meters, such as the [Noise Sentry RT-W](http://convergenceinstruments.com/product/noise-sentry-rt-wireless-network/).

Another option is [this USB dongle](https://www.bksv.com/en/products/sound-and-vibration-meters/sound-level-and-vibration-meter-accessories/Sound-level-meter-wireless-connectivity/UL-1050) with you are supposed to be able to connect to some sound level meters.

Answer (score 0):

They exist.  What is more, your local Council or Municipal Authority is bound to have some.  They will either loan or rent them to you.